# App Engine Deployment with Cloud Build failed with an "operation is already in progress" error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

I try to deploy a new version of app engine service with google cloud build with following steps:

1. deploy maintenance dispatch.yml to route all requests to maintenance page
2. Upgrade database
3. deploy new version
4. deploy dispatch.yml to route requests back to default service

The first three steps are working, but step 4 results in the following error:

an operation is already in progress

[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdQ5s.png)

The running GAE process is the one which is stopping the previous version.
So how can I find the running process and wait until it is stopped before
I deploy the dispatch.yml?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrating-traffic#migrating_traffic_to_a_new_version), to migrate traffic from one version to another, you should use the `set-traffic` command. So I think your step 4 should be replaced by the `set-traffic` command

Comment: the traffic change is made automatically on app deploy so I think not that this will help. I need the deploy of dispatch to route back from maintenance service (a static website) to the real web app.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by myself with the following statement:

```
gcloud app operations wait $(gcloud app operations list --format="value(id)" --pending --limit=1) || true
```

This would wait for a running operation. In my case I had to add this line twice because there where to running operations to wait for.